# Android Recursive Handler Call

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

Im trying to run 2 Handlers, but the trick is that when pass the first second the first thread run, when that thread finish(1 second) start the second thread, when the second thread finish(1second) it goes again with the first thread and the cycles continues.

My approach was using this:

```
val UI_HANDLER = Handler()

val UI_UPDATE_POSITION = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            locations()
            UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(this@MapsFragment.UI_UPDATE_NEW_POSITION, 1000)
        }
    }

    val UI_UPDATE_NEW_POSITION = Runnable {
        locations()
        UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(this.UI_UPDATE_POSITION, 1000)
    }
```

however im receiving a Recursive Problem, anyone can advice me what im doing wrong, im search in google but without any success.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't require 2 Runnables as you're only calling the same method in both Runnables(if this is the case then simply create a single Runnable calling locations() and set the handle to postDelayed() that Runnable every second). So, is that all the code related to those Runnables?

Comment: mmm... you're absolutely right sir.